# How to move category image above product listing column in magento 2.2.0?

Tags: category-listing, magento2.2.0

I want to move the category Image and category description in the column of product listing at category page. Now the Image and description is appearing above the 2column-left layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code in your `catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<move element="category.image" destination="content" before="category.products" />
<move element="category.description" destination="content" after="category.image" />
```